# Running a script on an AWS server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a script that I need to run once a day that requires a lot of memory.  I would like to run it on a dedicated amazon box.

Is there some automated way to build a box, download all required software (like ruby) and then run my script.  After the script is ran, I would like to shutdown the box.

The two options I can think of are:

1. I am thinking about hacking EMR to do this.  (My script is a mapper against an empty directory)
2. Chef - This seemed like too much for one simple script.

Comment: What Linux distro(s) do you prefer?

Comment: I generally pick ubuntu but I am open to others.

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish setting up a new EC2 instance on startup using the official Ubuntu AMIs, the official Amazon Linux AMIs, and any other AMI that supports the concept of a user-data script.

Create a script (bash, Perl, Python,

1. whatever) that starts with #!
2. Pass this script as the user-data when running the EC2 instance.
3. The script will automatically be run as root on the first boot.

Here's the article where I introduced the concept of a user-data script:

> Automate EC2 Instance Setup with user-data Scripts
>   http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-user-data-scripts

Your user-data script can install the required software, configure it, install your work script, and set up a cron job that runs the work script once a day.

**ENHANCEMENT:**

If the installation script don't take a long time to run (e.g., under an hour or few) then you don't even have to run a single dedicated instance 24 hours a day.  You can instead use an approach that lets AWS start an instance for you on a regular schedule.

Here's an article I wrote that provides details on this approach with sample commands:

> Running EC2 Instances on a Recurring Schedule with Auto Scaling
>   http://alestic.com/2011/11/ec2-schedule-instance

The general approach is to use Auto Scaling to start an instance with your user-data script on a regular schedule.  Your job will terminate the instance when it has completed.  They key is to suspend Auto Scaling's normal desire to re-start instances that terminate so that you don't pay for a running  instance until the next time your job starts.

Comment: Interesting.  Can I pass multiple files over to the instance.  I would like to pass 3 files:  A) Boostrap (installs required software) B) Config  C) Script which runs

Comment: Combine them into a single script.  Or, pass in a user-data script that downloads and runs each of the individual scripts from some safe place like S3 with authenticated URLs.

Comment: Nice one Eric. That's exactly what I needed.